# How does EOS21 protocol work on transfering (teleporting) Ethereum's ERC20 tokens to eos?

Tags: tokens, eosio.token, ethereum, erc20

Is there a tutorial on how one would transfer ethereum erc20 tokens to eos? Who initiates this "transfer" and does it go into an ERC20 eos smart contract? Who takes control of it then?